# Superagent POST request in a specific format within reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, superagent

so I'm working for my school on a blog application with react js.

I did a simple text editor and onClick I'm updating a state.

My database has this format :

```
var blogSchema = restful.model('blog-schema', mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
preview: String,
content: [{type: String, body: String}],
comments: [{ body: String, date: Date}],
createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
},{collection: 'blogApp'})).methods(['put','get','post','delete']);
```

So I want to POST with superagent, data to the content property, I have this sort of object when I'm working with my editor on react:

```
{type: "h2",
 body: "Some random text"},
{type: "p",
 body: "Some random paragraph"}
```

And so on, and all of this is stored in an array.

My POST request is this :

```
     ajax.post("http://localhost:3000/api/articles")
    .send({title: this.state.title, content: this.state.article})
    .end((err, res) => {
      if(!err && res) {
        console.log(res.body);
      } else {
        console.log("I'm sad right now, stackoverflow help me!");
      }
    })
```

Of course it returns an error, not the good format,

So how can I can I post with a single request all of objects ? because of course I want to post with all that the title, preview and some other thing, Why I say that ? simply because I was thinking of mapping the array and do a post request for each of this elements but maybe it's too heavy ?

Sorry for my english

Comment: It works with JSON.stringify(this.state.article) but it saves this :        "content": [
    "[{\"type\":\"h2\",\"body\":\"azeazeaze\"},   {\"type\":\"p\",\"body\":\"azeazeaze\"}]"
  ]

Comment: Ok Guys, now with this one : content: JSON.stringify({type: article.type, body: article.body})
I got this : "content": [
    "{\"type\":\"p\",\"body\":\"I love y'all\"}"
  ], is this weird or ... ?

Comment: Should I post the data in react and then process it within' an app.post() with express ? I forget to tell you that along with react I'm using express...

Comment: I find the answer, writing the solution soon.